# Php funções iguais retornam diferentes valores

Tags: php, return

Eu tenho esta função:

```
function login($username, $password) {
    $user_id = user_id_from_user_name($username);

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`)  FROM `users` WHERE
        `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}
```

Que é a que retorna o resultado correto (`true` se o username e pass combinarem)
mas esta em baixo, que não vejo dif nenhuma diferença nenhuma já não funciona. Alguém sabe o que estou a fazer de mal?

```
function login($username, $password) {
    $user_id = user_id_from_user_name($username);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`)  FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na primeira função, você está aplicando o hash MD5 na variável $password e sanitizando o $username **antes** de fazer a query sql.

Na segunda função, você está fazendo a consulta sql antes de aplicar o hash e o sanitize. Por causa da falta da aplicação do hash na senha, o resultado da consulta será claramente diferente.

Comment: Muito obgado era isso mesmo

Comment: Se possível, marque a resposta como aceita :)